# In the subtraction sum on the right $a, b$ and $c$ are digits and $a$ is less than $b$. What is the value of $c$? $\bar{ba}−\bar{ab}=\bar{c6}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here $\bar{ba}=a+10b$ and $\bar{ab}=b+10a$

Therefore $(a+10b)−(b+10a)=6+10c$

or $9(b−a)=6+10c$

or $c=\displaystyle\frac{9(b−a)−6}{10}$

Since $c$ is a digit, if by trial and error method we take $b−a=4$, then $c=3$
Therefore the value of $c$ is 3.

I am not satisfied with the approach. Is there any different approach and whether my procedure is correct? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have $(a+10b)-(b+10a)=9(b-a)$, which is divisible by $9$, so $c6$ has to be divisible by $9$.  The usual divisibility test for $9$ says the sum of digits of $c6$ must be divisible by $9$, so $c+6=9, c=3$

Answer (score 0):

We must have that $$a-b\equiv 6\mod {10}$$and $b\ge a$. The only possibilities are $$(a,b)=(0,4)\\(a,b)=(1,5)\\(a,b)=(2,6)\\(a,b)=(3,7)\\(a,b)=(4,8)\\(a,b)=(5,9)$$